# Calculating area of a rectangle strip

Tags: integration, circles, area, rectangles

I would like to calculate the red marked area . How to do it? with steps?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE, typically users won't react well to questions alone, it would be better if you included some of your attempts so that we know what to help you with.

Comment: you can use integration to find that area

Comment: It would depend on there the "rectangle" is. You don't have that information in the figure. If you move the line up or down, the area might change

Comment: Hi ya I used integral to calculate the area. Thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

One approach, which looks promising here, is to decompose the area into the sum and difference of shapes you can compute the area of.  I see a [circular segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment) inside another with another cut out, then cut in half.  I can't read the dimensions of your figure.  Trace it on graph paper and count squares is another simple technique.